# Prevent overlapping pie charts on a GADM ggplot map using geom_scatterpie

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I am attempting to recreate this graphic:

[Proportion of male snails in New Zealand lakes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WJ84.png)

This image shows an outline of New Zealand, with the pie charts distributed outside of the outline, and connected to lake coordinates with a line.  So far, I have code which creates pie charts on top of the coordinates of each lake:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(scatterpie)

## Download data from GADM - country level (0), no regional outlines
nz1 <- getData("GADM", country = "NZ", level = 0)

## Extract polygon corners and merge with shapefile data
nz1@data$id <- rownames(nz1@data)
nz1.ff <- fortify(nz1)
nz1.df <- merge(nz1@data, nz1.ff, by = "id", all.y = TRUE)

#Add datapoints for lakes (longitude & latitude of each lake, with male and female frequencies)
lakes <- read.csv("Map Pie Charts.csv")

## Plot map
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = nz1.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill="whitesmoke") +  
  geom_path(data=nz1.df, aes(long,lat, group=group), color="grey", size=0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(165, 180)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-50, -30)) +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x=long, y=lat), data=lakes, cols=c("Males", "Females"))
```

[Map with pies over lake coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhew7.png)
My question is whether there is code to adjust the placement of the pie charts, without manually entering new coordinates where I want them?  I've seen posts that "jitter" does not work.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the less fun answer is just brute forcing: have a second set of coordinates where you want the pie chart to be.  For funzies you can also create a line from the site point to Pie chart fairly easily.  I'd still love an answer that doesn't involve manually creating points, but this at least is something.